# Vectorize addition whilst removing NA

Tags: r, vectorization

I am trying to add a scalar to a vector. However, when my scalar is NA, I want it to be ignored, similar to the `na.rm = TRUE` argument used in `sum`.

ie.

```
1:3 + x
```

returns `NA NA NA` if x is assigned `NA`. I would like it to return `1 2 3`.
I tried

```
sum(1:3, NA, na.rm = T)
```

but this does not vectorize the addition and just returns 1+2+3 = 6.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I'd use `1:3 + coalesce(x, 0)` (or `1:3 + ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)`, if you don't have `dplyr` loaded)

Comment: Another option would be `rowSums(cbind(1:3, x), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Or `mapply(sum, 1:3, x, na.rm = TRUE)`...

Comment: You could get tricky and define your own new operator - `\`%+%\` <- function(x,y) if(is.na(y)) x else x + y` then `1:3 %+% NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` :

```
x <- NA
1:3 + replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
#[1] 1 2 3

x <- 2
1:3 + replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
#[1] 3 4 5
```